# Why won't my sed command work with double quotes?

Tags: bash, sed

I am using the following command to delete all text before a match in a file:

```
sed -n '/sweet/,$p' file
```

It works perfectly, but i need to change 'sweet' to a variable, as its a variable i assume i need to use double quotes instead of single quotes, however when i run this command:

```
sed -n "/$variable/,$p" file
```

i receive the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unexpected `,'
```

How can i make this command work?

Comment: Try `sed -n "/$variable/,\$p" file`. You want `$` in front of `p` to be literal. Otherwise, it thinks you mean a variable `$p`. Since it has no value, it looked like `sed -n "/$variable/,"`, thus the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single quotes tell shell to not perform any expansion at all and `sed` gets three arguments `-n`, `/sweet/,$p`, and `file`.

When using double quotes, variables get expanded. Presuming `variable=sweet` and `p` not being set, second `sed` call got the following three arguments: `-n`, `/sweet/,`, and `file`. Address specifier where `,` is not followed by anything is not valid and gave you the error you've seen.

If you want to mix a (literal) `$` and variable expansion in a single argument, you have few option:

- `"/$variable/,\$p"` which escapes the `$`
- `"/$variable/"',$p'` or similar mix of single and double quoted string parts to treat `$` in each of its segment as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would brake the single quote for use a double for the variable then reopen the single quote.

```
sed -n '/'"${var}"'/,$p' file
```

I know this is working, however I not really used it yet so I don't know if this is the right way to do this.